# Disable audio output of a program

Tags: audio, unix, shell

To disable text output we use `> dev/null`, for example,

`make > /dev/null`

But how to similarly disable audio output? For example,

`skype A>&1 /dev/null` or whatever.

**EDIT:**

If it's possible, I'd like to know a system-wide way that is compatible with not only `OS X`, or only with certain linux distribution, but with all of `cygwin`, `mac`, `linux` and `bsd` systems (so if I move from `OS X` to other unix-like environment, I don't get the exactly same problem.

Else it's not :)

Answer (score 1):

The way "> /dev/null" works is that it takes everything that a program will output into the terminal and puts it at /dev/null, where you can put things that you don't want. Getting rid of the text output is done through the thing that received the output (the terminal). If you want to get rid of audio, you'll need to go through the thing that receives the audio (PulseAudio, most likely).

You can use pacmd for this:

```
$ pacmd set-sink-input-mute <index> false
```

here, `<index>` is the index of the application in pulse audio. You can figure out which index it is with

```
$ pacmd list-sink-inputs
```

The program must already be running, and so must PulseAudio for it to show up here.

Edit: [Source](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting#Muted_application)

Comment: Something slipped your attention:

`$ pacmd set-sink-input-mute <index> true`

not false. Also, to adjust volume, you can also do

`$ pacmd set-sink-input-volume <index> 0x<%float_with_no_commas>`
e.g.

`$ pacmd set-sink-input-volume <index> 0x10000` sets to 100.00%